# How do I get the request to be detected

Tags: vbscript, http-post, webhooks, discord

The text file exists, the web hook exists, etc. I am using a discord web hook. The response is

```json
{"code": 50006, "message": "Cannot send an empty message"}
```

I have concluded that the way I formatted the request is incorrect. Probably the `Set oHTTP = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")` part.
How do I reformat the request correctly? Is it even possible to send a web hook using a .vbs file?

```
Dim time
user = CreateObject("WScript.Network").UserName
time = (FormatDateTime(Now, 2)& " "& FormatDateTime(Now, 4))
Set objFileToRead = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").OpenTextFile("C:\Users\"& user& "\Desktop\state.txt",1)
state = objFileToRead.ReadAll()
objFileToRead.Close
Set objFileToRead = Nothing
url = "" 'my discord webhook
avatar = "https://discordapp.com/assets/dd4dbc0016779df1378e7812eabaa04d.png"
req1 = ("{ \" & Chr(34) & "username\" & Chr(34) & ":\" & Chr(34) & _
       "Manage bot\" & Chr(34) & ", \" & Chr(34) & "avatar_url\" & Chr(34) & _
       ":\" & Chr(34) & avatar)
req2 = Chr(34) & ", \" & Chr(34) & "content\" & Chr(34) & ":\" & Chr(34) & _
       time & " " & user & Chr(13) + Chr(10) & state & Chr(34) & " }"
Set oHTTP = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
oHTTP.Open "POST", url, False
oHTTP.SetRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
oHTTP.SetRequestHeader "Content-Length", Len(req1+req2)
oHTTP.Send req1+req2
HTTPPost = oHTTP.ResponseText
MsgBox oHTTP.ResponseText
```

Comment: What does the message box say?

Comment: Remove the backslashes from your JSON string. Also, defining the string with properly escaped double quotes is probably a lot more readable than doing a metric ton of string concatenations: `req = "{""username:""Manage bot"",""avatar_url"":""" & avatar & ... & state & """}"`.

Comment: Thank you, it works now. However, whenever I run it, I get this message box pop up, https://vgy.me/6jYFKh.png Error: "Operation aborted" Edit: the line and char numbers are where the request variable is being sent, I added a bit more to the script.